# survey, rating + feedback card through the bot framework?

Tags: botframework

Is there a recommended way to present a rating survey to your bots users?
I currently use a ThumbnailCard including 5 buttons (5 stars, 4 stars, 3 stars, 2 stars, 1 star) and postBack messages that I catch to get the user input, but it does not translate very well in Skype (only 3 buttons are supported), and it is a unusual experience (I would prefer 5 stars where the user can click on any).

Also, I would like to include a free text feedback field in this card, and the ThumbnailCard doesn't allow that either.

Thank you for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Probably the best route is using Adaptive cards but it's not yet supported on Skype